# Grails not setting database up as expected

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Hi this have been going on for several months now and I have lost all hope.

I have 3 domains in question.

Product which is made up of Components, each Component can have alternative products.

Here are my models:

Product:

```
 class Product {
     String name
     String comments
     static hasMany = [components:Components]
 }
```

Component:

```
 class Components {
    Product product
    static hasMany = [alternatives:Alternatives]
 }
```

Alternatives:

```
class Alternatives {
    Product product
}
```

To populate this I am parsing an excel Spreadsheet here is the code that does it:

```
Product st = new Product(
    name: row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().toUpperCase(),
    comments: "test"
)
row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue().split("[|]").each {
    Product pro = Product.findByName(it.toUpperCase())
    if(pro) {
        Components c =  new Components(product: pro).save(flush:true)
        s.add(c)

        // Does not work
        //st.addToComponents(c)
    }
}
st.save(flush:true,failOnError:true)
```

This does not create a table in the database called product_components. this is what I would expect.
When I try and use addTo the component has a product instance associated with it, the product instance is then changed to the st product instance which I am trying to save it to.

I hope that makes sense.

I have found out that it is mapping the product in the Components domain as the component in the Product domain.

I am now assuming that using mapped by in the Product table may fix it

```
static MappedBy = [components : //do something here ]
```

Found the answer see bellow:

I had to add the following in my Product domain.

```
  static mappedBy = {components joinTable: [name:'product_components',
                    column:'COMPONENTS_ID',
                    key: 'PRODUCT_ID']}
```

and change the name of product to part_of in my Components domain.

Comment: Can you include your grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy as well?

Comment: You might find that `grails.util.DomainBuilder` simplifies creating the domain class instances

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up now, your `Components` class only allows one product. So you have a one-to-many relationship from `Product` to `Components`, this is the reason the join table `product_components` is not being created.

You are also trying to assign a `Components` instance to multiple products:

```
// To the 'pro' Product
new Components(product: pro)

// To the 'st' Product
st.addToComponents(c)
```

But your `Components` domain class only allows for one `Product`, which is why the referenced `Product` is being overwritten.

If you want your Components class to have more than one product (which is what the code you've written is trying to accomplish), you'll have to add the `Product` class to your `static hasMany` block on `Components`:

```
class Components {
    static hasMany = [alternatives: Alternatives, products: Product]
}
```

Then you can perform the following:

```
def c = new Components().save(flush: true)
pro.addToComponents(c)
st.addToComponents(c)
```

On an unrelated note, I would recommend making your domain class names singular, i.e. `Alternative` and `Component` to follow Grails' conventions and to make more sense.